# m3u8 chunks combined lagging

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

I wrote a script to download chunks (.ts) from a web page that stream some soocer videos and combine all the chunks in a one file. The issue is that the final result is a video "lagging", it seems that some frames are missing.

I encoded the references of the website to avoid get the question removed.

**m3u8 url**

BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9uZXdlZGdlLmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMS5lZGdlLm15Y2RuLmxpdmUvbGl2ZS92aW50ZXF1YXRyb2hyczIvdmludGVxdWF0cm9ocnMyXzIwMDAvaW5kZXgubTN1OA==)

**Referer and Origin headers**

BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9mdXRlbWF4LmFwcA==)

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#./hls-download.sh "$url" "$title" "$(date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")"

url_m3u8="$1"
title="$2"
duration=$(date -d "$3 minutes" +%s)

cmd_curl="curl -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Origin: BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9mdXRlbWF4LmFwcA==)' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9mdXRlbWF4LmFwcA==)' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' --retry 5 --fail --compressed "

mkdir -- "$title"

cd "$title"

while [[ $(date -u +%s) -le $duration ]]
do
    response=$(eval "$cmd_curl $url_m3u8")

    urls=$(echo $response | grep -oP '(https[^ ]*)')

    for url in $urls
    do
        filename=$(basename $url)

        if ! [ -f $filename ]; then
            touch $filename
            eval "$cmd_curl -O $url"
        fi
    done
done

cat *.ts > ../"$title".ts

cd ../

rm -rf "$title"
```

Run this script passing m3u8 url, program title and duration in minutes

```
./hls-download.sh BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9uZXdlZGdlLmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMS5lZGdlLm15Y2RuLmxpdmUvbGl2ZS92aW50ZXF1YXRyb2hyczIvdmludGVxdWF0cm9ocnMyXzIwMDAvaW5kZXgubTN1OA==) program 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I still looking an answer to my question but I found a better way to solve the issue.

```
ffmpeg -headers $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nOrigin: BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9mdXRlbWF4LmFwcA==)\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nReferer: BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9mdXRlbWF4LmFwcA==)\r\nSec-Fetch-Dest: empty\r\nSec-Fetch-Mode: cors\r\nSec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' -i "BASE64(aHR0cHM6Ly9uZXdlZGdlLmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMS5lZGdlLm15Y2RuLmxpdmUvbGl2ZS92aW50ZXF1YXRyb2hyczIvdmludGVxdWF0cm9ocnMyXzIwMDAvaW5kZXgubTN1OA==)" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "output.mp4"
```